# How to send a valid crsf token with angularjs $post service and symfony2

Tags: ajax, symfony-forms, angularjs-service, csrf-protection, angular-http

I think I read enough topics for posting this question... and I really want to know why my submission using ajax is invalid (The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form).

This is how I send my form data and the csrf token.

```
<form name="ReviewForm" ng-init="formData = { url: '{{ path('my_route') }}', token: '{{ csrf_token('review') }}' } ng-submit="sendReview(ReviewForm.$valid)" other parameters... >
```

In my angular controller :

```
myAppcontroller('FormManagerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.sendReview = function (isValid) {
        if (isValid) {
            $http.post($scope.formData.url, $.param({
                    'review[pseudo]': $scope.formData.pseudo,
                    'review[email]': $scope.formData.email,
                    'review[title]': $scope.formData.title,
                    'review[website]': $scope.formData.website,
                    'review[rate]': $scope.formData.rate,
                    'review[content]': $scope.formData.content,
                    '_csrf_token': $scope.formData.token
            }), {
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('ok');
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    console.log('ko');
                });
        }

    };
}]);
```

The name of my form is "review".

```
// Form type class
public function getName()
{
    return 'review';
}
```

I tried different names (_token etc...), I checked if `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}` and `csrf_token('review')` returned the same value but without success.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in symfony2 forms the elements `id` and `name` attributes are composed of the `getName()`+`field name`, in your case the token will have `id="review__token"` and `name="review[_token]"`, so, the framework will check that `review[_token]` is present in the post data. I think you need to change your `_csrf_token` param for `review[_token]` just like the others params.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought the token field was not linked to my review type because the field is not part of my review entity...